# How to create image type field in dynamic rows at config magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to create image type field in dynamic rows at configuration magento 2

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No proper solution found , i have did it with a different way.

Comment: Can you share how you have achieved it?